# convert python 2.7 timedelta.total_seconds() to equivalent in python 2.6

Tags: python, time, seconds

timedelta.total_seconds() is not supported in python 2.6. The code below works in python 2.7. Would anybody know how to convert to equivalent in 2.6?

Thanks

```
import datetime

timestamp = 1414270449
timestamp = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
```

---

Sorry,

I have the same code below. How do I implement total_seconds() in python 2.6 using

```
(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6`

import datetime

timestamp = '2014-10-24 00:00:00'
timestamp = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
print timestamp

timestamp = '2014-10-24 00:00:00'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
print timestamp
```

Thanks

Comment: why do you call `strptime()` on integer?

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternative to total\_seconds() in python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089558/alternative-to-total-seconds-in-python-2-6)

Answer (score 8):

It's all [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

> Equivalent to `(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6` computed with true division enabled.