# alternative to total_seconds() in python 2.6

Tags: python, time

In python 2.7 there is the total_seconds() method.

In python 2.6, it doesn't exist and it suggests to use

```
(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6
```

Could somebody show me how to implement it below?

Thanks

```
import datetime

timestamp = '2014-10-24 00:00:00'
timestamp = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
print timestamp

timestamp = '2014-10-24 00:00:00'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
print timestamp
```

Comment: what is wrong with using what the docs provide?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is - maybe you're confusing timestamps and timedeltas? After your program runs, the variable `timestamp` actually contains a `timedelta` object. If you named that `td` instead, the formula given above yields the expected result.

Comment: You missed that the documentation tells you that the formula requires that *true division is enabled*, e.g. `from __future__ import division`. Or convert one or the other operand to a float (explicitly, or implicitly by dividing by `10.0**6`, say).

Answer (score 16):

Here it is in a timedelta_total_seconds function and using 2.7 you can see that it gets the same output as using the total_seconds method.

```
import datetime


def timedelta_total_seconds(timedelta):
    return (
        timedelta.microseconds + 0.0 +
        (timedelta.seconds + timedelta.days * 24 * 3600) * 10 ** 6) / 10 ** 6


timestamp = '2014-10-24 00:00:00'
time_delta = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)

print timedelta_total_seconds(time_delta)
print time_delta.total_seconds()
```

Outputs

```
1414108800.0
1414108800.0
```

Comment: The `+ 0.0` is redundant once you follow the documentation and enable true division, `from __future__ import division`.