# using total_seconds function in python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, timedelta, python-datetime

I have a scenario where I need to use `total_seconds()` method but there is no option to run the same in python 2.7. In python 2.6 `total_seconds()` method doesn't exist.

It is suggested to use

```
(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6
```

could anybody help me here as how can I use it here in the following code.
or any alternative will be great.

```
   final = self.stats['FINAL']
    self.stats['START'] = start = final[0][1]
    self.stats['END'] = end = final[-1][2]
    self.stats['DELTA'] = delta = end - start
    self.stats['IS_AVAILABLE'] = is_available = final[-1][0]

    self.stats['AVAILABLE'] = {}
    self.stats['AVAILABLE'][True] = {}
    self.stats['AVAILABLE'][False] = {}

    for entry in final:
        is_available = entry[0]
        dstart = entry[1]
        dend = entry[2]
        edelta = dend - dstart
        etotsec = int(edelta.total_seconds())
        availability[is_available]['last'] = dend
        try:
            # Number of seconds in this status
            seconds = availability[is_available]['seconds']
            seconds = seconds + etotsec
            availability[is_available]['seconds'] = seconds
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['SECONDS'] = seconds

            # Update count
            count = availability[is_available]['count']
            count = count + 1
            availability[is_available]['count'] = count
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['COUNT'] = count
        except:
            availability[is_available]['seconds'] = etotsec
            availability[is_available]['count'] = 1
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['SECONDS'] = etotsec
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['COUNT'] = 1

        try:
            # Register entry
            registry = availability[is_available]['registry']
            registry.append(entry)
            availability[is_available]['registry'] = registry
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['REGISTRY'] = registry
        except:
            availability[is_available]['registry'] = []
            self.stats['AVAILABLE'][is_available]['REGISTRY'] = []

    self.stats['LAST_UP'] = lastup = availability[True]['last']
    self.stats['DOWN_COUNT'] = numdowntime = availability[False]['count']
    self.stats['DOWN_SECONDS'] = totdowntime = availability[False]['seconds']
    self.stats['UP_COUNT'] = numuptime = availability[True]['count']
    self.stats['UP_SECONDS'] = totuptime = availability[True]['seconds']

    self.stats['DOWN_PERCENTAJE'] = ptotdowntime = totdowntime * 100 / delta.total_seconds()
    self.stats['UP_PERCENTAJE'] = ptotuptime = totuptime * 100 / delta.total_seconds()
    self.stats['DOWN_LIST'] = downtimes = availability[False]['registry']
    downtimes.reverse()

    REPORT += "First entry recorded: %s\n" % start
    REPORT += " Last entry recorded: %s\n" % end
    REPORT += "        Is Available: %s\n" % is_available
    if not is_available:
        REPORT += "        Last time up: %s\n" % lastup
    REPORT += "        SAP Lifetime: %s\n" % delta
    REPORT += "         Unavailable: %s, %d times down, %.02f%% of lifetime\n" % (str(timedelta(seconds=availability[False]['seconds'])), numdowntime, ptotdowntime)
    REPORT += "           Available: %s, %.02f%% of lifetime\n\n" % (str(timedelta(seconds=availability[True]['seconds'])), ptotuptime)
    REPORT += "Last %d/%d downtimes:\n" % (self.props['SHOW_MAX_DOWNTIMES'], len(downtimes))

    for n in range(len(downtimes)):
        if n < self.props['SHOW_MAX_DOWNTIMES']:
            start = downtimes[n][1]
            end = downtimes[n][2]
            delta = end - start
            duration = str(timedelta(seconds=delta.total_seconds()))
            REPORT += "\t%2d - Down from: %s\t\tto: %s\tDuration: %s\n" % (n + 1, downtimes[n][1], downtimes[n][2], duration)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put that formula in a function, and use the function instead of a method:

```
from __future__ import division

def td_total_seconds(td):
    # note that this relies on true division being enabled with 
    # from __future__ import division.
    # alternatively, replace the 10**6 divisor with 10.0**6 or insert `0.0 +`
    # at the front, or explicitly convert either operand with float()
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6
```

This is the direct equivalent:

```
>>> timedelta(days=1, seconds=255423, microseconds=12345).total_seconds()
341823.012345
>>> td_total_seconds(timedelta(days=1, seconds=255423, microseconds=12345))
341823.012345
```

Then, where ever `object.total_seconds()` is used, you use `td_total_seconds(object)` instead. Some examples from the code you posted; the original line

```
etotsec = int(edelta.total_seconds())
```

becomes

```
etotsec = int(td_total_seconds(edelta))
```

The other lines become:

```
self.stats['DOWN_PERCENTAJE'] = ptotdowntime = totdowntime * 100 / td_total_seconds(delta)
self.stats['UP_PERCENTAJE'] = ptotuptime = totuptime * 100 / td_total_seconds(delta)
```

The last example looks like a left-over from refactoring perhaps? It doesn't make much sense, it creates a copy of a `timedelta` object only then to convert that object to a string. You can just directly convert the object to a string, no copying required. You can ever leave the string conversion to the printf-style string formatting on the next line:

```
REPORT += "\t%2d - Down from: %s\t\tto: %s\tDuration: %s\n" % (n + 1, downtimes[n][1], downtimes[n][2], (end - start))
```

This removes the need for the `delta =` and `duration =` lines preceding it.

Comment: There's also this similar question/answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089558/alternative-to-total-seconds-in-python-2-6 which adds a 0.0 into the mix.

Comment: @rrauenza: note that the Python 2.7 documentation I linked to includes: **computed with true division enabled**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201388/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-rrauenza).